# Is "where T : class" not enforced in any way at compile time or run time?

Tags: c#, class, generics, struct

In the following code, I pass a struct into a constructor that is expecting a class. Why does this compile and run without error (and produce the desired output)?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var entity = new Foo { Id = 3 };
        var t = new Test<IEntity>(entity); // why doesn't this fail?
        Console.WriteLine(t.Entity.Id.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Test<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }

    public Test(TEntity entity)
    {
        Entity = entity;
    }

    public void ClearEntity()
    {
        Entity = null;
    }
}

public struct Foo : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

If I change my `Main()` method so that it includes a call to `ClearEntity()`, as shown below, it *still* generates no error. Why?

```
static void Main()
{
    var entity = new Foo { Id = 3 };
    var t = new Test<IEntity>(entity);
    Console.WriteLine(t.Entity.Id.ToString());
    t.ClearEntity(); // why doesn't this fail?
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: `Foo` being `IEntity`, it will be boxed. The boxed instance is an instance of a class.

Comment: How can he compile `t.Entity.Id` when `Entity` is defined as type `TEntity` where `TEntity : class`, which doesn't implement `IEntity`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`where TEntity : class` forces `TEntity` to be a reference type, but an interface such as `IEntity` is a reference type.

See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx

> where T : class  |  The type argument must be a reference type, including any class, interface, delegate, or array type

Regarding your second question, you might think `t.ClearEntity()` would fail because it's assigning null to a variable whose type is a value type, but that's not the case.  The compile-time type of `Entity` is the reference type `IEntity`, and the runtime type (after assignment) is the null type.  So you never have a variable of type `Foo` but value `null`.

Comment: +1. Good explanation, thanks. This opens up some nice possibilities I didn't realize were available.

Comment: Thanks, I added a little more about why `ClearEntity` doesn't fail.  I thought it was worth noting that the runtime type stored in `Entity` is changed by assigning null to it.

Answer (score 2):

from the C# documentation:

> where T : class
>
> The type argument must be a reference type, including any class, **interface**, delegate, or array type. (See note below.)

Because you're passing the struct via an interface, it's still considered a reference type.

Comment: Because it's being boxed it actually is a reference type, it's not like it's a value type that just isn't being filtered by the `class` restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Within the .net runtime, every non-nullable value type has an associated reference type (often referred to as a "boxed value type") which derives from `System.ValueType`.  Saying `Object Foo = 5;` won't actually store an `Int32` into `Foo`; instead it will create a new instance of the reference type associated with `Int32` and store a reference to that instance.  A `class` constraint on a generic type specifies that the type in question must be some sort of a reference type, but does not by itself exclude the possibility that the type may be used to pass a reference to a boxed value-type instance.  In most contexts outside generic type constraints, interface types are regarded as class types.

It's important to note that not only are boxed value types stored like reference types; they behave like reference types.  For example, `List<string>.Enumerator` is a value type which implements `IEnumerator<string>`.  If one has two variables of type `List<string>.Enumerator`, copying one to the other will copy the state of the enumeration, such that there will be two separate and independent enumerators which point to the same list.  Copying one of those variables to a variable of type `IEnumerator<string>` will create a new instance of the boxed value type associated with `List<string.Enumerator` and store in the latter variable a reference to that new object (which will be a third independent enumerator).  Copying that variable to another of type `IEnumerator<string>`, however, will simply store a reference to the existing object (since `IEnumerator<string>` is a reference type).

The C# language tries to pretend that value types derive from `Object`, but within the guts of the .net Runtime they really don't.  Instead, they're *convertible* to types which derive from `System.ValueType` (which in turn derives from `Object`).  The latter types will satisfy a type constraint, even though the former ones will not.  Incidentally, despite its name, `System.ValueType` is actually a class type.

Answer (score 0):

I, likewise, assumed that constraint keyword `class` meant the same class as the type declaration keyword `class`, but it doesn't.

As explained in the other answers, the term `class` here is over-loaded, which seems to me to be a horrible decision for the C# language design.  Something like `referencetype` would have been more helpful.

Comment: A more fundamental problem is the fiction that value-type storage locations hold things that derive from `Object`.  Boxed value types derive from `Object`, but value-type storage locations don't hold those.  Fundamentally, a `class` constraint on `T` implies two things about e.g. `T foo;`: (1) the default value of `foo` will be a null reference; (2) `foo.bar()` will invoke the `bar()` method act upon a `T` to which `foo` holds a reference, without giving that method any access to `foo` itself.  Those things are no less true of boxed value types than of any other class type.